# Facebook SDK never setting the $user

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

i dont know what im doing wrong.
It always shows me the auth url, but i always click the link but still not setting me the app.

```
ini_set('include_path',"F:\fubolito\ajax.fubolito.py\inc");
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../ajax.fubolito.py/inc/config.global.php');
include('sdk/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => $fb['app_id'],'secret' => $fb['secret'],
'cookie' => true,
));

$facebook->setAccessToken($_GET['code']);

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if(!$user)
echo '<a href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'">Login</a>';
```

What im doing wrong ?

Comment: can you create a test page with the php sdk only, with login and logout?  i will try to login and see if there are errors in auth.  Even the default sample for php sdk will work for this test.

Comment: I added the try catch stuff and now works !
Thanks so much anyways Shawn !

Comment: awesome, i am going to post a generic solution with try catch for the users who come to same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YourAppId',
  'secret' => 'SecretKey',
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
  ));
//  
try { $user = $facebook->getUser(); } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {  }
//
$access_token = $_SESSION['fb_YourAppID_access_token'];
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
  $params = array (
  access_token => ''.$access_token.'',
  );
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
} else {
$params = array(
  scope => 'read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,read_friendlists',
  //redirect_uri => $url
  );
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
};

?>
```